# Insert space between characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, list, char

I have a string,

```
string aString = "a,aaa,aaaa,aaaaa,,,,,";
```

Where i want to insert to a List..But when i do using the following method,

```
List<string> aList = new List<string>();

aList.AddRange(aString.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

MessageBox.Show(aList.Count.ToString());
```

I get the count as only 4, But there are actually 8 elements even the final characters in between the (,) sign is blank.

But if i pass the string as shown below,

```
string aString = "a,aaa,aaaa,aaaaa, , , , ,";
```

It will be shown as 8 elements..Please help me on this, the default way thw program retrieves the string is like so,

```
a,aaa,aaaa,aaaaa,,,,,
```

Please help on this one, It would be great if i could add spaces to the empty area or any other way so that i could add all these characters in between (,) sign to the list.. even the blank areas. Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

```
string aString = "a,aaa,aaaa,aaaaa,,,,,";
var newStr = String.Join(", ", aString.Split(','));
```

Comment: But it adds an extra element and shows as 9 where it is actually 8..is it ok to just loop through the list with i < aList.Count -1 ?? or is there a another way?? thank you :)

Comment: @Hasitha split returns a blank entry after the last `,`. *"Is it ok or not"* depends on your case.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must remove `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

```
aList.AddRange(aString.Replace(",,", ", ,").Split(new string[] { "," }));
```

Comment: hey thanx for the reply :) but didnt actually solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can just `Replace` the space before split it.

```
aList.AddRange(aString.Replace(" ", "").Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Comment: hey,,thanx for the reply :) but this way doesn't work..it still says 4